# Dynamically load a Vuetify component in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I am trying to load vuetify components dynamically in a vue 3 project using the following code:

```
<template>
   <v-chip>try</v-chip>
   <component :is="object.tag">{{ object.content }}</component>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'component1',
  data: () => ({
    object: {
      tag: 'v-chip',
      content: 'hey'
    },
  }),
}
</script>
```

Trying this I get no errors, using v-chip component normally works fine but the second component doesn't work well and doesn't get initialized as a vuetify component instead I get the following:
[image]
I have tried using VChip or vChip but they also don't work and there is no errors at all. I also tried to use a none vuetify component, one that I have created and it loads successfully.

Comment: Please share your main.js file

Answer (score 0):

`object.tag` should be the imported component, not a string.

```js
// import only needed if ala-carte
import VChip from 'somewhere'
{ object: { tag: VChip } }
```